# I keep getting Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Unexpected closing tag "div". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag

Tags: html, angular

I keep this error but my code looks very fine on my dialog.html what am i missing here am suing angular 6 and im implementing matdialog from angulat material my codde looks very fine brothers

i tried deleting the div tag but the problem still persits on my chrome console

**here is my dialog.html**

```html
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.amount" placeholder="Amount">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="data.reason" placeholder="Reason">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
<div mat-dialog-actions>
  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>
  <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.amount" cdkFocusInitial>Update</button>
</div>
```

**here is the error on chrome**

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "div". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. For more info see https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags ("
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
  [ERROR ->]</div>
  <div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>
"): ng:///AppModule/DialogOverviewExampleDialog.html@8:2
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2175)
    at DirectiveNormalizer._preparseLoadedTemplate (compiler.js:17686)
    at compiler.js:17677
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2166)
    at DirectiveNormalizer._preParseTemplate (compiler.js:17677)
    at DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplate (compiler.js:17664)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata (compiler.js:19820)
    at compiler.js:25829
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at compiler.js:25828
syntaxError @ compiler.js:2175
_preparseLoadedTemplate @ compiler.js:17686
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:17677
then @ compiler.js:2166
_preParseTemplate @ compiler.js:17677
normalizeTemplate @ compiler.js:17664
loadDirectiveMetadata @ compiler.js:19820
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:25829
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:25828
_loadModules @ compiler.js:25825
_compileModuleAndComponents @ compiler.js:25805
compileModuleAsync @ compiler.js:25767
compileModuleAsync @ platform-browser-dynamic.js:223
compileNgModuleFactory__PRE_R3__ @ core.js:40263
bootstrapModule @ core.js:40598
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
0 @ main.ts:13
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
```

**Here is my editstudentsindebt.component.ts**

````
```import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';
import { User } from '../model/User.model'



@Component({
  selector: 'app-editstudentindebt',
  templateUrl: './editstudentindebt.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editstudentindebt.component.css']
})
export class EditstudentindebtComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'regno','amount','reason','action'];
  dataSource;
  user;

  users: User[];

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,private userservice:UserService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userservice.getAdmins()
      .subscribe((users: User[]) => {
        this.users = users;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(users);

      });
  }


  editUser(user) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
      width: '250px',
      data: user
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      this.user = user;
    });
  }

}


@Component({
  selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'dialog.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: User) {}

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}```
````

Comment: Self close the input tags and check

Comment: change your input tag such that it has closing slash / at the end : <input />

Comment: @GangadharGandi the problem still persists even after i do that

Comment: @GangadharGandi the problem still persists brother

Comment: So is that all your html? Or does it have any other code in dialog.html?

Comment: @GangadharGandi acoording to the error it says something like the div tag or something

Comment: yes brother @GangadharGandi

Comment: Kill your ng serve and try to run it again! And also I'm not able to reproduce it in the stacblitz

Comment: did that brother started it several time but the problem is still there @ng-suhas

Comment: I tested your html and I don't see any error. In fact the input tag doesn't need to be closed to avoid errors, yes it's good practice to do it but won't give you errors if you don't

Comment: true brother @devpato but when i run the angular it doesn't render atll and gives the error

Comment: I compared your code to the one in here https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview and the only difference I see is the extra mat-fields but it looks correct. Do you have more code in that html or just that?

Comment: also have you imported this ```import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';```

Comment: @devpato i have added the MatDialogModule and started the angular but again the problem still persists yes that the only code in html am implementing the matDialog

Comment: in your [(ngModel)]="data.amount" is the data object in your ts file? try adding it like [(ngModel)]="this.data.amount" if it is in your ts file.

Comment: Do you mind copy pasting this code into your app and let me know if it works. If it doesn't your problem is somewhere else  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5h7x2a?file=src/app/dialog-overview-example-dialog.html

Comment: here is where i took the example guys https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-modal?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable.component.ts

Comment: i have added the respective component